# Why is an object in an XMLHttpRequest sent to a Node/Express server empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a form that takes the email address and sends a transactional email back. I am using a XMLHttpRequest in vanilla JavaScript to send data to the server, but when I look at the data sent from index.html, it is only an empty object on the server side.

On the backend I am using Node and Express and Nodemailer. Nodemailer is working properly. I have been trying to figure out why the query object does not have anything in it.

```js
// Here is server.js

var express = require('express');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var app = express();

// Send index.html
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.sendfile('index.html');
});

// Where I should receive data from JS written in index.html
app.post('/send', function(req, res) {
  var mailOptions　 = 　 {
    to: req.query.to,
    subject: req.query.subject,
    text: req.query.text
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Here is my index.html with some JS in it -->

<div>
  <input id="to" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
  <input id="subject" type="text" placeholder="subject" />
  <textarea id="content" cols="20" rows="2" placeholder="Write something"></textarea>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<script>
  // When #submit is clicked it invokes a function to collect values and then makes a XMLHttpRequest like bellow
  data = {to: to, subject: subject, text: text};
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/send', true);
  request.send(data);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your XMLHttpRequest sends a 'GET' request but your express server is expecting a 'POST' request

Comment: @PHPglue the code he put up is a snippet of his actual code hence why it's undefined

Comment: Nothing is sent with `.send()` using `GET`, just the `.open()` URL is used. If you want to send data use `POST` or append the data to the URL like: `?to=val1&subject=val2&text=val3`. Either that or use jQuery, then you can just pass that data Object.

Comment: Really sorry about the mistake. I accidentally left .post instead of .get because I was trying out both pairs in different situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few things before this can work

- Decide whether you want to use GET or POST, you seem to be confused as to which one to use.  I would use POST because you're trying to send data for an email and not really trying to get data from the server.
- Change your app.post node function (assuming you want post)
- You need to send a string to the server, hence the json stringify
- Since your string is in json format you need to change the header "Content-Type" to "application/json"
- You need to change your request verb to 'POST' to match your server and what you are trying to accomplish

In your server you need to replace the app.post code with (you'll need to npm install body-parser)

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
// Where I should receive data from JS written in index.html
app.post('/send', function(req, res) {
  var mailOptions　 = 　 {
    to: req.body.to,
    subject: req.body.subject,
    text: req.body.text
  }
});
```

This should do the trick on the client

```
data = {to: to, subject: subject, text: text};
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/send', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

**Alternative Solution to XMLHttpRequest**

Alternatively, you can look at this library for sugar over the HTTP api - [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)

If you're using axios, it's as simple as

```
data = {to: to, subject: subject, text: text};
axios.post('/user', data);
```

or if you want to control what happens when you receive a response.

```
data = {to: to, subject: subject, text: text};
axios.post('/user', data)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log('success');
  })
  .catch(function (response) {
    console.log('error');
  });
```

Comment: I just implemented the changes and worked beautifully. I appreciate the alternative solution, too. I will try it out as well. This was literally the perfect answer!

Comment: no worries @jayscript would you mind ticking the solution and upvoting it?

Comment: This was my very first Stack Overflow question. I will upvote your answer as soon as I have accumulated 15 reputations! I just need 5 more...

Comment: What does "ticking the solution" mean? Is there a way to show I found the solution?

Comment: You as the question owner can approve one solution and it will get a green tick. Everyone else can also upvote solutions.  The tick should be located near where the upvote is.

Comment: @Yang Li `I would use POST because you're trying to send data for an email and not really trying to get data from the server.` Is this true when I try to embed a `div` under my form input field if there's an error with validation?

Comment: @Lanti Sorry not really sure by what you mean with embedding a div under your form input field

Comment: I have my `nodemailer` email sender script in my `router.post` and I have my template rendering in `router.get`. My problem is I want to send content to client with `handlebars` templating engine from `res.render` inside `router.get`, when the form sent. But seems like this is not working because the variables not be shared between `router.post` and `router.get`.

Comment: I'm not sure, you'll have to post some code somewhere

Comment: @YangLi - this is a great answer.  Thanks for sharing!