# Send plain text over XMLHttpRequest to Express server

Tags: javascript, express, xmlhttprequest

I'm making an XMLHttpRequest `post` request to my Express server.  I'm trying to send a string, but I'm doing something wrong.

Client:

```
const sendMessage = () => {
  const message = "This is a test."
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/messages/api/new-message/', true)
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    }
  }
  xhr.send(message)
}
```

Server:

```
router.post('/api/new-message', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Got it')
  console.log('req.body\n', req.body)
})
```

`console.log('Got it')` ensures that the request is going through successfully.

I also tried setting a request header: `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'plain/text');`, but it still didn't go through.

What *does* work is `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');` and `xhr.send(JSON.stringify({message: message}))`, but that's a JSON object.

**How do I send a string over an XMLHttpRequest `post` request?**

Comment: For anyone interested, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32084765/6946549) has a great solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that you tried `plain/text`, but that is incorrect, the correct header is  `text/plain`.

*from MDN*

> - using the POST method and setting the enctype attribute to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (default);
> - using the POST method and setting the enctype attribute to `text/plain`;
> - using the POST method and setting the enctype attribute to `multipart/form-data`;
> - using the GET method (in this case the enctype attribute will be ignored).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest